# Pass value to a dictionary type parameter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I'm new and interested about dictionary. 
I wrote a method on base repository like this:

```
public IList<DropDownSelectList> GetDropDownData(string valueColumn, string displayColumn, string orderByColumnName = "", Dictionary<string, object> paramList = null)
{
//do my tasks.....
...

if (paramList != null)
{
   int index = 0;
   args = new object[paramList.Count];
   foreach (var item in paramList)
   {
      whereCondition += " AND " + item.Key + "=@"+ index.ToString();
      args[index] = item.Value;
      index++;
   }
}
..........
}
```

Now when I'm calling the method from some child repository like this:

```
return base.GetDropDownData("DivisionID", "DivisionName", "DivisionName", null);
```

then it's ok.

But when I tried to send some value to the parameter then it doesn't work at all.

I tried like bellow:

```
return base.GetDropDownData("DivisionID", "DivisionName", "DivisionName", "DivisionID",1);
```

and also:

```
Contact oContact = new Contact();
return base.GetDropDownData("DivisionID", "DivisionName", "DivisionName", "DivisionID", oContact);
```

But I got the error:

> no overload method 'GetDropDownData' takes 5 arguments.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Because in your function you specified only 4 arguments. In first case you passed 4 arguments - and all okay. What you tried to pass in other cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
return base.GetDropDownData("DivisionID", "DivisionName", "DivisionName", "DivisionID",1);
```

With this:

```
return base.GetDropDownData("DivisionID", "DivisionName", "DivisionName", 
                     new Dictionary<String, object> { { "DivisionID", 1 } });
```

And if you want multiple parameters...

```
return base.GetDropDownData("DivisionID", "DivisionName", "DivisionName", 
                     new Dictionary<String, object> { 
                         { "DivisionID", 1 }, 
                         { "OfficeID", 3 } 
                     });
```

Etc..

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

"no overload method 'GetDropDownData' takes 5 arguments." This just mean that your method can not accept 4 arguments because your definition take 4. You can write another method with the same name that 5 arguments if you need the send more parameters. You can also add a parameter with default value at the end such that if you call this method with 4 parameters, it should automatically use the default value for the last parameter !